# How can I get HttpServletRequest in an customized AOP advisor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

**Context:**
In my Spring MVC application, I have an advisor that intercepts controller methods (My AOP works fine). In the advice class, I'm trying to extract information by calling HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser(). Then I need to load user's authorities from DB.

**My code**
Interceptor class (implements `MethodInterceptor`):

> private HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)
>   RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

In `web.xml`:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**Result/Problem**:

I still get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found`, the exception still suggests using `RequestContextListener` or `RequestContextFilter`.

I have searched a lot on Stack Overflow and other places but no luck. Any help will be appreciated! (Please bear me for the old question:P)

**Update:**

I think I am referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request and that's why RequestContextListener doesn't help?

Is there any way I can still get the current request?

Comment: What edit?  Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @Taylor I have added the stack trace. (I deleted some lines. It was 400+)

Comment: It looks like this is firing on initialization, which means there wouldn't be a request.  You should either make your Aspect retrieve request on demand or delegate to a prototype-scoped bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For future developer's reference**:
When you get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found exception` which suggests using a `RequestContextListener` or a `RequestContextFilter`.

You have probably run into one of the two following situations.

**Situation NO.1**

You are not using `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` (E.g. It's not in your web.xml or it is not a Spring MVC application).
Then you probably want to add `RequestContextListener` to your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

or `RequestContextFilter` (which does the same thing):

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then your code should just start working.

**Situation NO.2**

You want to get access to HttpServletRequest outside its original context, then following code should help:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

**Make sure you put the code inside your method rather than inside the method's class!**

The difference is as following:
*Inside class*: it is just an object needs to be created at initialization time, which will throw the exception because there is NO REQUEST AT ALL during this stage!

*Inside method*: it will be created at run time when there is an actual request coming in. This will work perfectly fine.